# Get current url when changing tabs in xul in firefox

Tags: javascript, tabs, firefox-addon, xul

I am trying to get the current URL after changing tabs in Firefox. Is it possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A complete example that logs the current URL to the Error Console each time a new tab is selected:

```
function LOG(msg) {  
  var consoleService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/consoleservice;1"]  
        .getService(Components.interfaces.nsIConsoleService);  
  consoleService.logStringMessage(msg);  
}  

function onTabChange() {
    var href = gBrowser.contentDocument.location.href;
    LOG(href);
}

window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    gBrowser.tabContainer.addEventListener("TabSelect", onTabChange, false);
}, false);

window.addEventListener("unload", function(e) {
    gBrowser.tabContainer.removeEventListener("TabSelect", onTabChange, false);
}, false);
```

Comment: i have another questions , how can i run jquery on the document page, using xul ?, i found some solution, but none of them really help.