# XUL event listener for page load (in current tab only) or tab switch

Tags: xul, onload

Is there a simple script which will allow me to be notified if the a page is loaded in the current tab or if a new tab is now in focus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I've found. I hope it helps someone else:

```
// http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8355354/get-current-url-when-changing-tabs-in-xul-in-firefox
window.addEventListener("load", function(e) {
    gBrowser.tabContainer.addEventListener("TabSelect", phoenix.onTabChange, false);
}, false);

window.addEventListener("unload", function(e) {
    gBrowser.tabContainer.removeEventListener("TabSelect", phoenix.onTabChange, false);
}, false);
```